# How to change PreferenceActivity theme?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the theme for the PreferenceActivity in my app and I just can't get it to work.

This is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <SwitchPreference android:title="Auto Clear" android:key="autoclear" android:summary="Clear the command line when the code is being executed." android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <ListPreference android:title="Choose a theme" android:negativeButtonText="" android:dialogTitle="" android:key="theme" android:entries="@array/themesList" android:entryValues="@array/themesList" android:defaultValue="Default" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And this is the PreferenceActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}
```

And the result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: Do you want to change the theme for you whole app or just the PreferenceActivity?

Comment: have you seen these. http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/dress-up-your-preferenceactivity/
http://liquidlabs.ca/2011/10/17/override-android-preference-activity-colors/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried applying the theme on the activity tag in the manifest? This is how I have done it before -

```
<activity 
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:name="com.example.MyPreferenceActivity"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
  android:exported="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></activity>
```

**EDIT:**

The other option you could try is to override `onApplyThemeResource(Resources.Theme theme, int resid, boolean first)`. Looking at the android source code the setTheme will internally call method.

```
/**
 * Called by {@link #setTheme} and {@link #getTheme} to apply a theme
 * resource to the current Theme object.  Can override to change the
 * default (simple) behavior.  This method will not be called in multiple
 * threads simultaneously.
 *
 * @param theme The Theme object being modified.
 * @param resid The theme style resource being applied to <var>theme</var>.
 * @param first Set to true if this is the first time a style is being
 *              applied to <var>theme</var>.
 */
protected void onApplyThemeResource(Resources.Theme theme, int resid, boolean first) {
    theme.applyStyle(resid, true);
}
```

Comment: But I want to change the theme programmatically, because in the settings the user can change the theme. so everytime the PreferenceActivity starts I want to change the theme through the code.

Comment: Ahh I see. I have updated my post above. Hope that helps solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

At last i found out how to change theme of "PreferenceActivity" programmatically(via java code)

To change theme just do like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Holo_Theme_Light);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
```

Always call `setTheme(R.style.yourtheme);` method before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` method. By doing this it will produce result as shown below.

[image]

That's all.

If yo call `setTheme(R.style.yourtheme);` method after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` method it will produce result as shown below.

[image]

Note: Themes are not recognize by nested PreferenceScreen. To apply theme to that nested PreferenceScreen you have to make an another PreferenceActivity for that nested PreferenceScreen and call `setTheme(R.style.yourtheme);` method there.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the background you could use

```
public class FractalPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity  {
   .......

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.gradient); 
    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

           .......
    }
```

}

Comment: It's not just the background, the R.style.AppTheme is a whole new theme.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this approach:
for API below 11 I use(values directory, themes.xml file):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"></style>

</resources>
```

for higher (for example values-v14 directory, themes.xml file):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

</resources>
```

and manifest:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Android will choose a theme based on device's API automatically, and no need to specify any themes in activities (manifest) or grammatically in code...

[image: themes]

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna sound stupid, but using `setTheme()` will work on all your fragments, but not the main preference activity.  Set this in the manifest file, and it will suddenly start working.

I set the theme dynamically based on user preferences, calling `setTheme()` before the `onCreate` from theme manager object (it also doles out various colors and `drawables` that can be changed by the theme that I don't want to set in styles ... mainly because its too confusing to figure out what is what).

No idea why setting it in the manifest makes `setTheme()` work.  Just some glitch specific to the preference activity I guess.